# Scenario Execution Status ########## ---->>>> UNDEFINED error

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

trying to run the feature file in the intellij but I am getting

> Scenario Execution Status ########## ---->>>>  UNDEFINED

error multiple time in console though i have defined the steps in  step-definition file

The runner file structure is correct seems.

Runner File:

[image]

Configuration:

[image]

I am able to run the feature file through Runner file. But while I am trying to run the same by right clicking on the Feature file getting the above error

Comment: Please check if your glue is correct

Comment: Also could you share your feature file and step definition please

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cucumber docs FAQ](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/):

### Cucumber says my steps are undefined, but I have implemented step definitions!

If Cucumber is telling you that your steps are undefined, when you have defined step definitions, this means that Cucumber cannot find your step definitions. You’ll need to make sure to specify the path to your step definitions (glue path) correctly.

By default Cucumber-JVM will search in the package (or sub-packages) of the runner class. You can also tell Cucumber-JVM explicitly which packages (and sub-packages) to search, with:

```
 @CucumberOptions(glue = {"<package>", "<package>", "<etc>"})
 public class RunCucumberTest{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Glue is incorrect when you trying to execute from Feature file.Change your glue to same as your runner class, it should work.